# regex in powershell - not change three characters before text

Tags: regex, powershell

Is there any easy way to do this?

input:  `123215-85_01_test`

expected output: `01_test`

Another example

input:  `12154_02_test`

expected output: `02_test`

There will be always string "test", but different numbering before

for example this code..

```
$path = "c:\tmp\*.sql"
get-childitem $path | forEach-object {


   $name = $_.Name 
   $result = $name -replace "",""  # I don't know how write this regex..
   $extension = $_.Extension
   $newName = $prefix+"_"+ $result -f, $extension
   Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName

}
```

Comment: Easy way to do what? Where is your regex? Where does that input and output come from? Where is the code that generates this?

Comment: now there is example

Comment: So you always need the part at the end? It is _always_ what follows the second last underscore? You don't even _really_ need regex for this then if that is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @briantist I really enjoy that post as it covers a lot of ground. Are you using that for "gimmie the regex" questions as a place for OP's to start?

Comment: @Matt yeah exactly, I was clued into it from [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed) and it seemed like a good idea to me for questions that don't show any research. It has a lot of good information to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you go go at this. Simple split and join or you can use one of many regexes....

**Split on underscore and rejoin last 2 elements**

```
$split = "123215-85_01_test" -split "_"
$split[-2..-1] -join "_" # $split[-2,-1] would also work.
```

**Regex to locate the data between the last underscores**

```
"123215-85_01_test" -replace "^.*_(\d+)_(.*)$", '$1_$2'
```

Note this fails if there is more than 2 underscores.